# understanding destructuring in nodejs

Tags: node.js, destructuring

Below is simple code to illustrate use of let and destructuring in nodejs

```
function main(){
  let options = {};
  let [r, s, e] = [1, 2, 3];
  if(true){
    options = {a: 12}
    [r, s, e] = [3, 4, 5];
    console.log(options, r, s, e);
  }
}

main();
```

output - [ 3, 4, 5 ] 1 2 3

Output is weird. It should be {a: 12} 3 4 5

when i put semicolon at end of line 5

```
options = {a: 12};
```

i get correct output - {a: 12} 3 4 5

I simply cannot justify what difference semicolon is making?

Comment: all lines must end with `;` or you get weird effects.  `;` is meant to separate your code by statements, not end your lines.

Comment: Yet another example of why leaving semi-colons out of your code is dangerous and should not be an accepted practice.  I realize you may have not meant to do that here, but it's amazing to me how many people program without  semi-colons and think it's a safe practice.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript handles Automatic Semicolon insertion in cases when your syntax is actually breaking. The following conditions are checked

- A semicolon will be inserted when it comes across a line terminator or a '}' that is not grammatically correct. So, if parsing a new line of code right after the previous line of code still results in valid JavaScript, ASI will not be triggered.
- If the program gets to the end of the input and there were no errors, but it's not a complete program, a semicolon will be added to the end. Which basically means a semicolon will be added at the end of the file if it's missing one.
- There are certain places in the grammar where, if a line break appears, it terminates the statement unconditionally and it will add a semicolon. One example of this is return statements.

Please refer this article for more details: [Semicolons- to use or not to use](https://dev.to/adriennemiller/semicolons-in-javascript-to-use-or-not-to-use-2nli)

In your case its breaks the first rule because

```
if(true){
    options = {a: 12}
    [r, s, e] = [3, 4, 5];
    console.log(options, r, s, e);
  }
```

will be treated as

```
if(true){
    options = {a: 12}[r, s, e] = [3, 4, 5];
    console.log(options, r, s, e);
  }
```

which basically is equivalent to dynamic object value reference and assignment like

```
 options = {a: 12}[3, 4, 5] = [3, 4, 5];
```

and `{a: 12}[3, 4, 5] = [3, 4, 5];` will actually make the object value set to `{a: 12, 3: [3, 4, 5]}`

However at this point options is also assigned to `[3,4,5]`

Answer (score -1):

on not using semicolon at end of line 5 nodejs parser assigning [3, 4, 5]
to options variable and variable r, s, e remains unchanged

It is good practice to use semicolon at end of every statement to avoid error like this